# Event when an entry is enabled

Tags: entries, events, status

I've been looking for an event that get triggered when an entry is moved from a disabled to enabled status.

Currently I'm trying to find it through the `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT` event but I have no idea what the previous status of the entry was so I can't tell if it was just updated:

**current**

```php
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(Event $event)
    {
        $element = $event->element;

        // Get the status, but I don't know the previous status.
        $status = $element->status;
    }
);
```

I also had this pointed out to me https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-events-setstatusevent.html but I don't know what emits this event as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's awkward.

The `SetStatusEvent` was removed way back in the Craft 3.0 launch, but the class itself was never removed (will fix that for the upcoming 3.4 launch).

There isn't really a clean replacement for it.

One way would be to listen to the `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` event, run a separate database query to get the current status from the database and compare the status to the element that was passed in to see if it changed.

3.4 will give you another option - you could listen to `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT`, then check the `dirtyAttributes` array to see if the status has changed, since elements now keep track of what attributes have changed on a given request.